# How to detect if method is called with 'await' a.e. returns Promise

Tags: react-native

I write a plugin and I have several signatures of the same method:

- with callback: `foo(param1, param2, callback)`
- without callback: `foo(param1, param2)`
- with Promise: `foo(param1, param2): Promise<string>`

So I wrote:

```
function foo(param1, param2, callback) : Promise<string>{
    if(callback){
        fooCallback(param1, param2, callback);
    }else {
        return fooPromise(param1, param2);
    }
}

function fooCallback(param1, param2, callback){
    return RNMyPlugin.foo(param1, param2, callback);
}

function fooPromise(param1, param2) : Promise<string>{
    return RNMyPlugin.foo(param1, param2);
}

function foo(param1, param2){
    foo(param1, param2, null);
}


local.foo = foo;
```

My problem is:

I don't know how to detect if user calls my API `foo(param1, param2)` or `await foo(param1, param2)`

In 1st case user wants to call:

```
function foo(eventName, eventValues){/**/}
```

in 2nd case:

```
function fooPromise(param1, param2) : Promise<string>{/**/}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not make the return value an object with a property indicating what function it's returning from?

Comment: @Nerdragenhow to make it? can u give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
function foo(eventName, eventValues){
    return {
        from: "function"
        returnValue: /*return value here*/
    }
}


function fooPromise(param1, param2){
    return {
        from: "promise"
        returnValue: /*return value here*/
    }
}
```